# Exceptions Tasks with ContinueWith

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Example 1**. The exception of the task from which the ContinueWith method is called (**t1**) does not apply to the task created by this method (**t2**). And you need to handle this exception using wait methods.

**Question 1**: Do I understand correctly?

**Example 2**. It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks#handle-exceptions-thrown-from-continuations):

> If the continuation is an attached child task that was created by
> using the TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent option, its
> exceptions will be propagated by the parent back to the calling
> thread, as is the case in any other attached child.

As I understand it, this means the exception of the task created by the ContinueWith method with TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent (**t2**) should be extended to the task from which the method (**t1**) was called. However, I don't see any exceptions.

**Question 2**: Do I understand correctly? Why there are no exceptions? How should the exception be handled in this case?

**Question 3**. What are the ways to handle exceptions other than using wait methods in case of using method ContinueWith?

**Example 1. Code**:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            void MyMethod1()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(1);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                throw new Exception();
            }

            void MyMethod2(Task t)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(2);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);                
            }

            Task t1 = new Task(MyMethod1);
            t1.Start();

            Task t2 = t1.ContinueWith(MyMethod2);
                        
            t1.Wait(); //AggregateException. Inner Exception: Exception_WasThrown
            t2.Wait();                       
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2. Code**:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            void MyMethod1()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(1);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);               
            }

            void MyMethod2(Task t)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(2);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                throw new Exception();
            }

            Task t1 = new Task(MyMethod1);
            t1.Start();

            Task t2 = t1.ContinueWith(MyMethod2, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                        
            t1.Wait(); //No Exception                                 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `AttachedToParent` configuration is something that hardly anyone uses today. It was a bad idea from the beginning (2010), and Microsoft would happily go back in time and uninvent it, if this was possible. It's still supported and you can use it, but realistically don't expect much help from the community for solving `AttachedToParent`-related problems. The interest for this API is somewhere between low and non-existent!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Thanks. Then I added a third question. What are the ways to handle exceptions other than using wait methods in case of using method ContinueWith?

Comment: The `ContinueWith` method returns a `Task`. You can handle the exception of this task the same way that you would handle the exception of any other task. There is nothing special to the `ContinueWith`-generated tasks. As a side note, [it's not recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) to use the `ContinueWith` without specifying the `scheduler` argument. It's a [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) API in general, that should be used sparingly.